# Plotting side by side charts using matplotlib using

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I am trying to plot two donut charts side by side using matplotlib in python.

First of all I am creating the donut chart using the following logic:

1. Create a simple pie chart;
2. Pick a position for the chart using the `add_axes` function;
3. Add a **patch** (white circle in it so it can look like a donut chart);
4. Display the side by side charts on the screen.

   ```
   fig= plt.figure()
   circle1 = plt.Circle((0,0), radius= .7 ,color='white')

   ax1= fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1],aspect=1)
   ax1.pie(x= values, labels= KA, startangle=30,radius=1.2)
   ax1.add_patch(circle1)

   circle2 = plt.Circle((0,0), radius= .7 ,color='white')
   ax2 = fig.add_axes([1,0,1,1],aspect=1)
   ax2.pie(x=values2, explode=explode, labels=KA2,startangle=30,radius=1.2)
   ax2.add_patch(circle2)

   plt.show()
   ```

When it runs the function `plt.show()` it only displays the first donut chart, with a very strong zoom in it...

What has been driving me crazy is the fact that if I run the following function:
`plt.savefig('testplot.png',bbox_inches='tight')`
it saves a png file just like I want...

How can I do that on the `plt.show()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create the second axes outside the figure. The figure goes from 0 to 1 in both directions. If you start your second axes at position 1, it will go from 1 to 2, which is outside the shown figure.

Either use subplots

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"aspect" : 1})
```

Or create the axes within the figure boundary,

```
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0,0,0.45,1], aspect=1)
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.55,0,0.45,1], aspect=1)
```